# FOSUserBundle multiple user types

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am building an application where I have (at least) two different user types, let's say buyers and sellers. Each user type should have its own logic (registration form/process, profile, rights, ...) but I would like to use FOSUserBundle with each user, in order to have a common management on some points.

I am actually blocked by registration forms ; it happens that I can't declare different forms into FOSUserBundle, and after some research it seems to be impossible. Some answers that I found suggests to use my own registration form, but then

1. How to link it with FOSUserBundle ?
2. Should I populate myself the user table in controllers/forms ?
   This way the different users would allextends the User from FOSUserBundle, and then I should
   manage the different forms myself without extending those from
   FOSUserBundle ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: You could try creating your own forms for each user type and then use the FOS User Manager Service to handle the persistence and updates of that user in the controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [PUGXMultiUserBundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle) is what you are looking for. It extends [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) and allows you to have different registration forms etc...

Comment: Yep I found that bundle in the meantime, and it works great ; thanks !

Comment: This is an old post and it so happens that PUGXMultiUserBundle does not seem to be supported anymore especially for Symfony 4. 
So I'm wondering do you know any alternatives?