# Diffferents Registrations Forms and Doctrine inheritance

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I have an issue. I work with FOSUserBundle, but I need two differents user types. So I've implemented Doctrine inheritance for User Entity and I've created two different child User entity (Customer and Business). They have two roles.

Now, I need to create two different Registration Forms: RegistrationCustomerForm and RegistrationBusinessForm for save the data in different tables and sets their roles. How can I do this? Do i need to override RegistrationController and RegistrationTypeForm from FOSUBundle?

Thanks, 
Stek

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FOSUserBundle multiple user types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463150/fosuserbundle-multiple-user-types)